# Customizing the google map visualization in GMAP3

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

Want to change the google map visualization as : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Custom Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=de) for this. There is a [Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) available that makes it easier to create a styled map.